# Drupal views 2 Feed display adds surrounding html to items

Tags: xml, drupal, view, feed

I have a view that has a Default display and a Feed display.
When I go to the url of the page, it displays the info ok, but I have a JwPlayer flash file that's trying to read that xml. The problem is Drupal is surrounding each element with a bunch of divs and classes that I don't want. I just want to have the path to some audio files and path to image files for each item. All those divs also show in the preview of the Feed in the view.
Audio file 1
/home/drupal/site1/files/testaudio1.mp3
/home/drupal/site1/files/testaudio1_thumb.jpg

Is there a way to prevent all the extra html to output?

Answer (score 0):

You need [Semantic CCK](http://drupal.org/project/semantic_cck) which allows you to override the markup aded by default by the content.module.